# Create a new partition in apacheds without restarting the server

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I want to create a new partion in the Apacheds M14 without restarting the server.
I am able to create a new partition by restarting the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ApacheDS cannot create/activate a new partition without restarting after the appropriate configuration elements were added. However this is not the case in embedded mode.